# I modified the question should this be reopened?

Tags: discussion

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82256/how-exactly-exact-calculation-can-this-guy-have-70k-damage-if-his-intelligence

Looks like I missed that improved critical damage also improve damage that's listed on the damage. I didn't know that before.

I modified the question to ask how various factors lead to how damage is actually computed.

What do you think?

I see. I've read that. The reason why I think my question will add value is because many people want to have 70k damage too, and the screenshot pretty much proof that it can be done. Not available on that other questions.

Also answers on that other questions "may be" wrong. For example, somebody said, attack speed actually improve hydra.

Comment: I'd say no. I understand you put a lot of effort into asking the question, but it's still too specific.

Comment: We already have a question about how damage is calculated. Generally speaking, if there's a broad version of the question already, narrower versions of the question are closed as a dupe of the former.

Comment: The answer being wrong on the original question does not mean that we ask another question.  We downvote wrong answers.  As for hitting 70K DPS, that's what build questions, which have already been asked, are for.

Answer (score 5):

No. It shouldn't be reopened.

Really, I think that your question, as written is too specific still, by focusing on that individual screenshot, rather than asking the broader (and, IMO, more interesting) question of how the damage stat is calculated as a whole. Using the 70k screenshot that you're so curious about as an example in such a question would be fine, but the point is that the question should/could have been structured in such a way as to be more broadly applicable with an answer that later visitors could more readily apply to their own circumstance.

**That said**, I'd advice against making such an edit to your question at this point. Because, while that would certainly be a better question, if reopened, it would simply be closed immediately all over again, this time, as a duplicate of this question: [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is DPS Calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-dps-calcu/67844#67844)

That answer breaks down the formula for the character sheet's "Damage" stat, and includes all of the details of what stats and factors influence it. Plugging in the numbers from your screenshot should answer your question in full.